# How can I embed ActiveX-EXE (out-of-process server) into Excel spreadsheet

Tags: c++, com, ms-office, activex

Here I have an ATL-based ActiveX (DLL) that can embed into excel-spreadsheet.
I changed this to EXE(out-of-process server) by using ATL::CAtlExeModuleT and the entry point, WinMain().
But excel shows error msg - "cannot insert object" after servername.exe /RegServer.

svchost.exe spawns a process 'servername /Embedding' then I've got only above error msg.

I want figure some out:
 1. Can excel embed ActiveX EXE?
 2. And how can I do this?

I tested the component (EXE) in:

- My OLE Client
- MS's TestCon
- WSH, var object = new ActiveXObject("ExcelControl.Sample");

These seem to good for me.

in Excel:

- CreateObject works but this only for COM, this does not provide properties Left, Top, Width and Height
- `=EMBED("ExcelControl.Sample.1", "")` and `Worksheet(1).OLEObjects.Add "ExcelControl.Sample.1"` failed after following steps

  1. looks the component up
  2. reads type lib from the exe and write it down to temp/Excel8.0
  3. svchost.exe spawns the exe with /Embedding option

And I tried to write ActiveX(EXE) by Win32API.
In Excel, The EXE was spawned with /Embedding by svchost, but no one calls IClassFactory::QueryInterface despite CoRegisterClassObject's succeseeded.
Other containers can create the ActiveX(EXE) by CreateObject and QueryInterface.

the control (has no event) is:

```cpp
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CSample :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public IDispatchImpl<ISample, &IID_ISample, &LIBID_ExcelControlLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>,
    public IPersistStreamInitImpl<CSample>,
    public IOleControlImpl<CSample>,
    public IOleObjectImpl<CSample>,
    public IOleInPlaceActiveObjectImpl<CSample>,
    public IViewObjectExImpl<CSample>,
    public IOleInPlaceObjectWindowlessImpl<CSample>,
    public ISupportErrorInfo,
    public IQuickActivateImpl<CSample>,
    public IDataObjectImpl<CSample>,
    public IProvideClassInfo2Impl<&CLSID_Sample, NULL, &LIBID_ExcelControlLib>,
    public CComCoClass<CSample, &CLSID_Sample>,
    public CComControl<CSample>
{
```

this code is based on http://alex.info Roman Ryltsov

http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/ExcelControl/

Comment: No, any COM component with a visual representation in the spreadsheet must be an in-process server.  Like Roman's.

Comment: @HansPassant That's not true. E.g. you can embed a Word document into Excel spreadsheet. What is true though is that ATL doesn't provide the complete OLE server implementation out of the box; it's geared towards in-proc ActiveX controls. There are lots of complicated details to make OLE work. One can use MFC (which does provide all or most of the necessary scaffolding), or implement significant chunks by hand.

Comment: I know ActiveX potentially works in out-of-process. But "Microsoft Word Document" could not embed as an ActiveX Control in generic way like other controls.